# Java-syntax for explicitly specifying generic arguments in method calls

Tags: java, generics

What is the syntax for explicitly giving the type parameters for a generic Java method?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The following is **not** the syntax

```
<ArgType>genericMethod()
```

It seems the type arguments **must** come after a dot as in

```
SomeClass.<ArgType>genericMethod()
this.<ArgType>genericMethod()
p.<ArgType>genericMethod()
super.<ArgType>genericMethod()
SomeClass.super.<ArgType>genericMethod()
SomeClass.this.<ArgType>genericMethod()
```

Comment: How would this work for an `import static` method?  It's not attached to a class or `this`, and as you state the first syntax listed does not work.

Comment: @Coderer  Well the static method must be in some class, so you can use `SomeClass.<ArgType>genericMethod()`. If you didn't import the class, then you use the FQN of the class.  I'm sure you know this and were hoping for a more satisfying answer. Personally I don't see why the `<ArgType>genericMethod()` syntax couldn't be added to the language; does it create an ambiguity?

Comment: I actually hadn't tried the FQN of the class, I just switched from `import static pack.MyClass.someMethod; someMethod();` to `import pack.MyClass; MyClass.<ArgType>someMethod()`, but of course it's still more verbose than the "wish this worked" counterexample you give in the answer.

Comment: This is called *type witness*.

Comment: Yes.  Sometimes *type arguments* are called *type witnesses*.  That's good to know, and I hadn't known it before. The JLS uses the term *type argument*. The Generics trail of the Java tutorial sometimes use *type argument* and sometimes uses *type witness*.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. But this is so awkward.

Answer (score 89):

According to the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) that would be for example:

```
Collections.<String>unmodifiableSet()
```

(Sorry for asking and answering my own question - I was just looking this up for the third time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A good example from `java.util.Collection` of specifying a generic method which defines its own generic type is [`Collection.toArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29) where the method signature looks like:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

This declares a generic type T, which is defined on method call by the parameter `T[] a` and returns an array of T's.  So the same instance could call the toArray method in a generic fashion:

```
Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
collection.add(1);
collection.add(2);

// Call generic method returning Integer[]
Integer[] ints = collection.toArray(new Integer[]{});

// Call generic method again, this time returning an Number[] (Integer extends Number)
Number[] nums = collection.toArray(new Number[]{});
```

Also, see the [java tutorial on generic type parameters](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this with the part about explicitly giving a type parameter to a call (compare my answer). Then it would be a good canonical answer; as it is it doesn't even answer the question, since the parameter is deduced implicitly by the compiler in the call. :-)