# Java Generic on method with Functional Interface parameter type

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I cannot figure out why this code don't compile :

```
package Desktop;

import java.util.function.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static <T, U> Long myMethod( Function<T, U> methodParam ) {
      return methodParam.apply("Today is happy day!");
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println( <String, Long>myMethod( Long::valueOf ) );
   }

}
```

So i receive this on console:

```
..\Desktop\MyClass.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
          System.out.println( <String, Long>myMethod( Long::valueOf ) );
                                            ^
..\Desktop\MyClass.java:15: error: ';' expected
          System.out.println( <String, Long>myMethod( Long::valueOf ) );
                                                                     ^
2 errors
```

I am expecting to use generics to include type for the lambda on method parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
public static <T, U> U myMethod(Function<T, U> methodParam, T t) {
  return methodParam.apply(t);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(myMethod(Long::valueOf, "Today is happy day!") );
}
```

`myMethod` accepts a `Function` with generic parameters, so you can't always call its `apply` method with a `String` argument and expect it to return a `Long`.

Instead, you can pass to it the `String` argument, and change its return type to `U`.

Of course, this code will throw a `NumberFormatException`, since you can't convert that `String` to a `Long`.

Comment: 2 Errors generated by it.

Comment: @marcius.tan that's strange. I compiled and executed this code. It throws an exception, as I said, but it passes compilation.

Comment: public static <T, U> U myMethod( Function<T, U> methodParam, T t ) {
    
          return methodParam.apply(t);

    
        }
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {

   Long ddd = myMethod( Long::valueOf, "today is a good day!");
    
          System.out.println(ddd);
    
       }

Comment: my recent reply compiles but .class interpret throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "today is a good day!"

Comment: @marcius.tan As I said, it's not a surprise this code throws an exception.

Comment: I'll try to think about it again in next days. I think i am lacking the fundamental here. Thx for all the respond. I appreciate!

Comment: @marcius.tan What don't you understand? Are you surprised that `Long.valueOf("Today is happy day!")` throws an exception?

Comment: OMG! this is what happens when i got stuck for extended time. I put "168" at the beginning but then i changed to "today is a good day!". Now, after "168" it compiles + interpret fine! god*mn!..

Answer (score 1):

As Eran's answer suggests, you have 2 problems: In the definition of myMethod and in the call of the method.

1) You declare methodParam as a function with input type T and output type U. And then in myMethod you treat it as if T was String and U was Long. This is only how you want to call the method but the compiler does not know anything about T and U at this point. Erans solution for myMethod works as myMethod returns a value of type U (instead of Long) and receives a parameter of type T instead of calling apply() with a string.

2) The call of myMethod() in the main method: either as in Erans example the type parameters are implicitly given by your parameters. Otherwise, if you need to express them explicitly for some reason, @ernest_k showed the solution (also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012781/java-syntax-for-explicitly-specifying-generic-arguments-in-method-calls)).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `Long.valueOf()` takes only either `String` or `long`. From the type parameter `T`, the compiler concludes that the `Function` takes `Object`, it will not allow it since there is no method as `Long.valueOf( Object )`.

You may have to change `myMethod()` to this signature:

```
public static <T, U> Long myMethod( Function<String, Long> methodParam ) { //Both type parameters are explicit
    return methodParam.apply("Today is happy day!");
}
```

Or this, which may throw `NumberFormatException`:

```
public static <T, U> Long myMethod( Function<String, U> methodParam ){ //Input  type parameter is explicit
    return (Long) methodParam.apply( "Today is happy day!" );
}
```