# Incompatible types Void and Object - Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

Below code throws

```
"Incompatible types. Required Sample<Void> but create was inferred to Sample<T>. Incompatible equality constraints:Void and Object".
```

```
public class SampleClass{
  public static <T> Sample<T> create(String str) {}
}

Sample<Void> sample = SampleClass.create("abc");
```

Comment: What's `Sample`? Please provide a [mcve], [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/T596o0).

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012781/java-syntax-for-explicitly-specifying-generic-arguments-in-method-calls/3012789

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java-syntax for explicitly specifying generic arguments in method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012781/java-syntax-for-explicitly-specifying-generic-arguments-in-method-calls)

Comment: pls ignore this question.. it was something wrong on my side. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work.

Full example:

```
public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample<Void> sample = SampleClass.create("abc");

    }

    public static <T> Sample<T> create(String str) {
        return null;
    }

    private static class Sample<T> {
    }
}
```

Compiles and executes just fine (with JDK 11).